# Water Deluge and Flame Trenches

Tags: launch-site, water, launchpad

After years of seeing a water tower so close to the launch pad, I’m now just starting to realize it has a purpose. I was a fool to think the water tower had been there for years and they just could not move it.

Are there any videos of the water deluge in action?

Also how does the flame trench operate?

Lastly, water is the size of the directional paddle/grids? I recall having an interest in the previous NASA Program, but SpaceX has brought the program to the public in an incredible manner to help a guy like me to understand the entire process.

Everyday Astronaut is also a great asset!

Comment: It is bad form to ask multiple things in one question across the Stack Exchange network. It also is bad form to ask questions that have already been asked and answered. Both of these questions have been asked and answered: [What is the purpose of the jets of water often under rocket engines during launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1551) and [What is a flame trench?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2979)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the jets of water often under rocket engines during launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-jets-of-water-often-under-rocket-engines-during-launc) This was an arbitrary choice; there are multiple duplicate candidates.

Comment: @DavidHammen When new users ask their first question they don't have good form or bad form.  I think the first received response ever should not be "You have bad form". Instead, try something like "Welcome to Stack Exchange! It turns out that both of these questions... You can ask as many good questions as you like, no need to put multiple questions in one post... and have fun!"

Comment: Hi @PaulHagstrom and *Welcome to Space!* Luckily there is an abundance of information on all of these topics both within this site and in YouTube. Are there any videos of deluge systems in action? Sure! How does a flame trench operate? Well that's a good question, and I'll bet if you edit this question and narrow it down to "How exactly does a flame trench work, what are the design considerations in terms of flow and materials, especially directly under the rocket where the flames must turn by 90 degrees" that will be an excellent question, well received, and probably well-answered.

Comment: Once you edit your question it will trigger a review process that will hopefully result in it being reopened in a day or so. The process might feel a bit clunky at first, but stick with it. Stack Exchange works amazingly well once you get used to it. *Have fun!*